# How to add Parameters to Sitecore Page url

Tags: sitecore-api

My Question is How we can add parameters to a Sitecore URL. any help is appreciated

example: `example.com/insights/blogs/?category=Skaitmeninė%20transformacija`

Answer (score 6):

for example if you want to add query string to current item you can use :

```
var url=LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
string urlQS = WebUtil.AddQueryString(url, "category", "Skaitmeninė transformacija"); // "http://www.mysite.net?print=1"
```

**Update**:

If you want to add from Sitecore you can use General Link field. In your code you will have next lines to render with query string:

[image]

```
 var linkField = (LinkField) Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Link"];
 var url=linkField.GetFriendlyUrl();
```

Comment: Thank you @sitecore Climber, is there a way to do it in Sitecore itself rather in coding?

Comment: I updated my answer